# React-Flux: Error with AppDispatcher.register

Tags: javascript, flux, reactjs-flux, reactjs

I am trying to set up the most basic app in Flux-React. Its sole goal to is fire an Action, which gets sent through the Dispatcher to a Store that has registered with the Dispatcher. The store the logs the `payload` to Console.

Everything besides the Store is working well, but as soon as it hits `AppDispatcher.register`, Flux throws the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'ID_1' of undefined
```

Here is the code of the file causing the error, but I've put up the entire project at https://github.com/bengrunfeld/react-flux-dispatcher-error, and you can find the offending file in [src/js/stores/AppStores.js](https://github.com/bengrunfeld/react-flux-dispatcher-error/blob/master/src/js/stores/AppStores.js)

```
var AppDispatcher = require('../dispatcher/AppDispatcher');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var AppConstants = require('../constants/AppConstants');
var assign = require('object-assign');


var CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';

var AppStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
  emitChange: function() {
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
  }
});

AppDispatcher.register(function(payload){
  console.log(payload);
  return true;
})

module.exports = AppStore;
```

Comment: Up voted youtube video, question and answer here :)  Looking forward for another video.

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial. It is great. Your original version is working, but when I make it my own. I need to move the register callback to AppDispatcher.js, not in the AppStore.js. See more here: https://github.com/kenpeter/simplest-flux

Comment: hi - how would I update the main view rather than pushing to a console.log? So lets say everytime I clicked the button it took in another record from a json file and outputted on screen? cheers

Comment: Use `setState()`. Here, follow this link https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because of the drought of documentation of biblical proportions for Facebook Flux, I didn't know that I was using code from previous versions.

In `AppDispatcher.js`, you need to define AppDispatcher in the following way using the `new` keyword:

```
var Dispatcher = require('flux').Dispatcher;
var assign = require('object-assign');

var AppDispatcher = assign(new Dispatcher(), {
  handleViewAction: function(action) {
    this.dispatch({
      source: 'VIEW_ACTION',
      action: action
    });
  }
});

module.exports = AppDispatcher;
```

Here is a link to a repository with the working code: https://github.com/bengrunfeld/react-flux-simple-app

Comment: Not sure I would call http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html#content a drought, exactly.

Comment: I would definitely call it that. Go onto Youtube and show me *one* tutorial of how to create a simple application using Flux. Also, while there is definitely official documentation about Flux, it is unintuitive and written for experienced engineers who just "get it", not for more junior engineers who need more hand-holding.

Hence [@rynclark](https://twitter.com/rynclark)'s comment - "If you're like me and you wanted to go further with React, you more than likely would've checked out Flux, had a glance, closed the tab and then reassessed your life as a Javascript developer."

Comment: @fisherwebdev - In the first tutorial, one code block has *86 lines of code*. How is anyone (especially a new or junior dev) supposed to keep that much code in their head while they are learning a new framework, attempting to understand the underlying concepts, and getting the hang of how to use it practically? It's simply intimidating. Please, allow me to re-write your docs and your user-base will triple in a week.

Comment: FYI, @fisherwebdev, I made this video to help junior programmers understand Flux. [http://youtu.be/o5E894TmHJg](http://youtu.be/o5E894TmHJg)

Comment: I'm using es6 and changed my code from [ import Dispatcher from 'flux' ] to [ var Dispatcher = require('flux').Dispatcher; ] and it started working.  Not sure what the es6 syntax for this would be.